# Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected with Kafka Java client

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I try to make Kafka producer Java codes on Windows 10. First, below is my Kafka producer codes.

```
Properties kafkaProdProperty = new Properties();
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, systemProp.get("kafka.brokerlist"));
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "0");
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(1));
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(20000));
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(1));
kafkaProdProperty.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, Integer.valueOf(133554432));

Producer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(kafkaProdProperty);

String line = //Read from hadoop file system continuously

ProducerRecord<String, String> kafkaProducerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, line);
kafkaProducer.send(kafkaProducerRecord, new KafkaProducerCallback());
```

The execution of Kafka producer Java codes starts successfully without any exceptions. But the input line  become longer and bigger, the warning message is thrown like below,

```
2021-07-27 10:30:28 WARN  NetworkClient:780 - [Producer clientId=producer-8049] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-07-27 10:30:28 WARN  NetworkClient:1077 - [Producer clientId=producer-8049] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-07-27 10:30:28 WARN  NetworkClient:780 - [Producer clientId=producer-8049] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-07-27 10:30:28 WARN  NetworkClient:1077 - [Producer clientId=producer-8049] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I think this issue is related with Kafka Java resources. But I have no idea what to configure. When the smaller input lines are set on Kafka producer parameter, it throws no warning messages like above.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: 1) Error says Kafka isn't running, so you need to provide server logs, not client logs 2) Kafka has a default maximum message size, and not meant for file transfer